# Quantity for abbreviations of plural terms

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, abbreviations

I have two questions which I think are so closely related that they should be grouped together.

#### Quantity for an abbreviation that stands for a plural

*Context*: The author is trying to explain what open market operations (OMO). The term "open market operation" is meaningless in the context, it is always a group of operations.

*Which of the following sentences is grammatically more correct?*

> OMO **refer** to the buying or selling..........

or,

> OMO **refers** to the buying or selling.........

The second one is what I found in print. But I think it should be the first one.

#### Abbreviations that stand for the singular

*Do I need to pluralize an abbreviation if it stands for the singular form?*

> 5 kg. **costs** about €10.

or,

> 5 kg. **cost** about €10.

or,

> 5 **kgs. cost** about €10.

P.S.:- Please do let me know if the context is insufficient for the first one. Does the context even matter in such cases?

Comment: This "OMO", is it an organization or just a term coined for the occasion, what is it?

Comment: @Alenanno Open market operations are operations by which the Fed sells/buys US treasury in/from the secondary market (meaning normal investors such as you and me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **first part of your question**, I would treat OMO as singular because I'd be referring to a single concept represented by that abbreviation:

- "OMO refers to the buying or selling..."

If you were writing about a number of OMOs, then I'd use this:

- "OMOs refer to the buying or selling..."

For the **second part of your question**, the first and third options are both correct, but the first is usually more appropriate instances (I also suggest changing "about" to "approximately" {or abbreviate to "approx"})...

In the scenario where I was selling 5 kg. packages of something, I prefer "5 kg. costs approximately €10."

To elaborate further, if I was selling based on weight that the buyer chooses arbitrarily, the businessman in me would prefer something along the lines of "1 kg. costs approximately €3, and for higher quantity orders 5 kg. costs approximately €10."

Comment: I have a follow up question on about and approx. I have seen some people use circa as well --does it fit here?

Comment: I don't think the third option is correct.  You can't pluralize unit abbreviations, otherwise you couldn't tell if `ms` was meters or milliseconds.  Also, it's more correct to leave off the period, e.g. "5 kg costs about €10." But otherwise I agree with this answer.

Comment: @MonsterTruck "circa" means "in approximately" (literally "about") but it is generally used for dates.  "Jesus was born circa 4 A.D." for example.

Comment: @Monster Truck:  "Circa" (abbreviated "c.") is typically used with dates.  For example, "in c. 1980 AD the popular style of music changed drastically due to..."

Comment: But if I were to expand OMO to Open Market Operations then would I use the plural form?

Comment: Thanks for the off-topic clarification on `circa`.

Comment: @Matthew, good point. So to sum up what you and Randolf have said, I can avoid all the confusion by using `5 kg. mango boxes cost` or `5 kg. soap costs`.

Comment: @Monster Truck:  You're welcome.  Also, I would keep to the same rule but possibly _italicize_ or enclose the unabbreviated form "within quotation marks."  Preserving the initial Upper-Case Letters is important though because those three words represent a specific piece of terminology that is (usually?) abbreviated.

Comment: @Randolf Makes sense.

Comment: @Randolf: I agree with @Matthew, kg doesn't have the dot after it... So "5 kg" is fine.

Comment: If you can buy a 5 kilo box of apples for £3, then "5 kilograms of apples" **is a single thing** - it's singular, not plural. So, "costs".